# How does glibc find global init functions?

Tags: c, linux, assembly

I was learning/playing around with the linker and assembly

I notice every file that has a global constructor generates a function similar to

`_GLOBAL__sub_I_*`

How does glibc find these? I tried looking in linux auxiliary vector and didn't see it anywhere. It doesn't seemed to be mentioned in musl c. I'm not sure where to look

Comment: The constructor addresses are probably put into a special section. See [this article](https://maskray.me/blog/2021-11-07-init-ctors-init-array)

Answer (score 1):

They are not found.  They are indeed not searched for.  Calls to them are just chained in a special section generated by the compiler that is built as each compiled unit is processed.  Finally, when the linker is called, a final piece of code is added to jump/return back to the rest of the runtime initialization code.  This making the full initialization code a compact piece of code that can be called at program start.

Of course, this is just one way of initializing the runtime if you are a compiler writer.  Normal C only compilers don't need this special section, because initialized code goes, with its initialization data to the `.data` section.  But C++ or mixed C/C++ compilers do need it to make C++ constructor calls for global static objetct instances.  Indeed, the process is a bit more complex than the simple I explained here, because class constructors have to be called in a specific sequence (superclass constructors have to be called first for each instance, before the instance's class constructor is used) GlibC has nothing to do with that code, or has no reason to search the initialization code.

On other side, if you search for that code, you are tying yourself to GCC and a specific version also, you will run in trouble if you need in the future to switch to another compiler.  You should consider every identifier starting with `_` as reserved and non portable.  More important, if you are searching for undocumented parts of the compiler.  Those are more probably changed in future versions than exposed, documented features.